# Unable to get the required result using update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to update the data using record by record below scenario.

Required output: patient will able to Admit/Re-admit multiple times in hospital, if a patient readmitted multiple times in hospital after the first visit, first visit record will get Re-admission=0 and Index=1. This visit should cal Index_Admission of that patient. using this index_admission should calculate the 30-day readmission.

**Current Output:** 
[image]

Calculation: 
From index_admission discharge date to next admit_visit date,

> 1) if the diff is having less than 30 days, readmission=1 and Index=0
>
> ```
>  else readmission=0 and Index=1 should be update.
> ```

For checking this every time should check using the latest index_admission discharge_date.

To get this result i written below logic, but it's updating readmission=0 and Index=1 after 30-day post discharge of using first index admission.

```
UPDATE Readmission
SET Index_AMI = (CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, (SELECT
            Sub.Max_Index_Dis
        FROM (SELECT
            Patient_ID,
            MAX(Discharge_Date_Time) Max_Index_Dis
        FROM Readmission
        WHERE Index_AMI = 1 AND FPR.Patient_ID = Patient_ID
        GROUP BY Patient_ID) Sub), FPR.Admit_Date_Time) <= 31 THEN 0 ELSE 1
    END),
    Is_AMI_Readmission = (CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, (SELECT
            Sub.Max_Index_Dis
        FROM (SELECT
            Patient_ID,
            MAX(Discharge_Date_Time) Max_Index_Dis
        FROM Readmission
        WHERE Index_AMI = 1 AND FPR.Patient_ID = Patient_ID
        GROUP BY Patient_ID) Sub)
        , FPR.Admit_Date_Time) <= 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
FROM Readmission FPR
WHERE fpr.index_ami IS NULL
```

**Expected Result:**
[image]

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Best Regards,
Nagendra

Comment: The "Expected" result(blank) u need is "Unexpected" :) Please post current output and required output and it will be help full if u create sqlfiddle!

Comment: Make the query with proper alignment...

Comment: Do you need to use a set based update? A cursor would make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying to help.
I some how managed to solve it using temporary tables.
If there is any issues, especially performance, with this approach please feel free to comment/criticize.

```
/*------------ To moving all Patient_Readmission data into temp table -------------*/
IF EXISTS (select  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    WHERE o.xtype IN ('U') 
 AND o.id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Readmission')
)
Begin
DROP TABLE #Readmission
End

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    WHERE o.xtype IN ('U') 
 AND o.id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Readmission')
)
BEGIN
select Patient_ID,ID,Encounter_Code 
,Admit_Date_Time,Discharge_Date_Time
,Is_AMI_Readmission,Index_AMI
into #Readmission
from Patient_Readmission
END

GO
/*----------- To get Max Index discharge_date for all patients where index=1----------*/
IF EXISTS (select  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    WHERE o.xtype IN ('U') 
 AND o.id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg')
)
Begin
DROP TABLE #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg
End

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    WHERE o.xtype IN ('U') 
 AND o.id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg')
)
BEGIN
select Patient_ID,Index_AMI,Max(Discharge_Date_Time) Max_Index_Dis 
into #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg
from #Readmission where Index_AMI=1 group by Patient_ID,Index_AMI
END


Declare @var int 
Set @var=(select Min(Patient_ID) from #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg)
While @var is not null
    Begin
        Declare @Var_En int
        declare @maxDisch datetime
        Set @Var_En=(Select Min(ID) From #Readmission Where Index_AMI Is null and Patient_ID=@var)
        While @Var_En is Not NULL
        Begin
            set @maxDisch = dateadd(dd,-1,(select max(Max_Index_Dis) from #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg where Index_AMI=1 and Patient_ID=@var))
            while (@maxDisch < (select max(Max_Index_Dis) from #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg where Index_AMI=1 and Patient_ID=@var))
                begin
                    Update #Readmission
                        set Index_AMI=(Case When Datediff(DD,(Select Max(Max_Index_Dis) From #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg Where Index_AMI=1 And Patient_ID=@var),FPR.Admit_Date_Time) between 0 and 31 Then 0 Else 1 End)
                        ,Is_AMI_Readmission=(Case When Datediff(DD,(Select Max(Max_Index_Dis) From #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg Where Index_AMI=1 And Patient_ID=@var),FPR.Admit_Date_Time) between 0 and 31 Then 1 Else 0 End)
                    From #Readmission FPR where Patient_ID=@var and ID=@Var_En and Index_AMI is NULL

                    set @maxDisch = (select max(Max_Index_Dis) from #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg where Index_AMI=1 and Patient_ID=@var)

                    delete from #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg

                    insert into #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg
                    select Patient_ID,Index_AMI,Max(Discharge_Date_Time) Max_Index_Dis 
                    from #Readmission where Index_AMI=1 group by Patient_ID,Index_AMI
                end

        SET @Var_En = (SELECT Min(ID) FROM #Readmission WHERE ID> @Var_En)
        End

    SET @Var = (SELECT MIN(Patient_ID) FROM #Each_Pt_Max_Dsrg WHERE Patient_ID > @var)
    End
```